# FILTERXML returns #VALUE

Tags: xml, xpath

The XML document that I am trying to filter:

https://www.sec.gov/cgi-bin/browse-edgar?action=getcompany&CIK=0001652044&CIK=0001652044&type=10-K%25&dateb=20161220&owner=exclude&start=0&count=10&output=atom

`EDGARXML10K` is a named range that contains the XML from above link.

```
=FILTERXML(EDGARXML10K,"/feed/entry/content[@type='text/xml' and filing-type='10-K']/accession-nunber")
```

There are two filing types in the XML, `10-K` and `10-K/A`. How can I extract the `accession-nunber` for `10-K`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried: `"/feed/entry/content[@type='text/xml' and filing-type='10-K']/accession-nunber/text()"`

Comment: I didn't tried it with FILTERXML. I just checked the xpath against that XML and it returns the value of accession-number node, as you want, but maybe it is different with FILTERXML...